# Is calling a function pointer to generated code undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is there a way, in purely standard C++, to somehow call a function generated within a buffer?

Let's assume:

1. We've used implementation-specific knowledge (and obv. architecture-specific) to generate the byte sequence implementing some function in an array of `char`.
2. This implementation correctly matches the implementation's calling convention, and other relevant parts of the ABI, so that it will actually function correctly if called as C++ function
3. The buffer is correctly marked as executable

I.e., all the architecture / ABI hurdles have been overcome, all we need to do is actually call this block of code.
The question is: is there a standards-compliant way to create a function pointer to this and call said function pointer without hitting undefined behavior?

As I understand it, it is implementation-defined if we can cast a pointer to an object type to a function pointer type. I also believe that it is implementation-defined if said pointer will point to the same logical address as the original pointer. The obstacle is the call: from the perspective of the implementation, all I've done is try and cast a pointer to an array of chars into a function pointer and then call it. If said ptr was one to an object type, I know this would be violating strict aliasing rules, and would be undefined behavior. But is it undefined behavior or merely implementation-defined what will occur if I attempt to call this function pointer?

Comment: C++ is not ABI aware, therefore it is UB. Though if you can find documents on a particular implementation specifying behaviour in such case, I believe it can be considered implentation-defined.

Comment: C/C++ implementations on POSIX-compliant systems are required to support calling a function pointer casted from `void*` in order for `dlsym` to work. Furthermore, the wording in the working draft is that such a cast to / from an object type is conditionally supported, and a call on an fptr is undefined only if it was casted from a function of the wrong type. There is no such language for when / if it points to something that isn't a function.

Comment: From a perspective of the C++ standard, it is undefined behaviour.    From a perspective of your ABI specification, or in a specification of your host operating system API (e.g. POSIX), it may be perfectly well defined behaviour.   From a perspective of some other ABI specification (or a specification of some other host operating system) it may be undefined behaviour.

Comment: C++ is underspecified. Language spec says it’s UB. However, almost 100% of real-world software doing that anyway and it works fine, because GetProcAddress( windows ) and dlsym ( Linux ) both return `void*` values to be casted into a callable function pointer.

Comment: Re: "We've used implementation-specific knowledge" -- by definition, that means that the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior means only that the language definition doesn't tell you what your program does. It doesn't mean that bad things will happen.

Comment: @Hrisip "_C++ is not ABI aware, therefore it is UB_" Which means even linking C and C++ is UB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you ask about code such as:

```
char buffer[200] = "some valid operations";
void (*func)() = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(buffer);
func();
```

I see in the standard in [C++ expr.call 7.6.1.3 Function call](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.call):

> 1. A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function.
>    [...]
>    The postfix expression shall have function type or function pointer type.
>    For a call to a non-member function or to a static member function, the postfix expression shall either be an lvalue that refers to a function [...], or have function pointer type.

The `func` in the above code is an lvalue that refers to a `char` array and not to a function. The following points in the standard describe other cases of function call expression, such as virtual function call or call to a destructor of some object. These points also do not apply here. To summarize, the standard does not define what will happen when the function call expression is applied to a lvalue that refers to a object that is a `char` array. Because it's not defined, hence it's undefined behavior.

> is there a standards-compliant way to create a function pointer to this

Just cast it, via `reinterpret_cast`. The resulting value is implementation-defined.

> and call said function pointer without hitting undefined behavior?

No.

> Is calling a function pointer to generated code undefined behavior?

Yes.

> Is there a way, in purely standard C++, to somehow call a function generated within a buffer?

No.

> But is it undefined behavior or merely implementation-defined what will occur if I attempt to call this function pointer?

Undefined behavior.

Comment: "to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment" is one of the "range of permissible behaviors" allowed for undefined behavior anyways, so it seems like this might be permitted even within the language of the standard. So "undefined behavior," but a consistent (and implicitly supported) one on the implementation(s) I care about. I suppose I misunderstood "undefined" to mean "the optimizer will trample over this."

Comment: "Undefined behavior" doesn't mean that this behavior is not permitted. It means only that _this standard_ imposes [no requirements on behavior on such programs](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined). Other standards may specify behaviors of code that is undefined according to the C++ standard. `suppose I misunderstood "undefined" to mean "the optimizer will trample over this."` This is exactly what this means. If no standards document the behavior, then the compiler is allowed to do what it wants.

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation-defined [what the conversion **means**](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8.sentence-2), so the implementation can choose to interpret it as a pointer to some function “defined by the implementation” (as if its standard library contained all *possible* functions).  I’m not sure that implementations actually **document** support for this technique (as required for implementation-defined behavior), but it’s only reasonable to interpret that as a bug in their documentation.